# Combining mod_rewrite and mod_ext_filter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, filter

To refine xml output of my server, I have written a mod_ext_filter that strips part of the xml and sends the rest.

`ExtFilterDefine wfs_geometry_stripper mode=output intype=text/xml \
                 cmd="/www/vhost/mapserver/cgi-perl/wfs_stripper.pl"
 <Location /wfs/stripped >
    SetOutputFilter wfs_geometry_stripper
 </Location>`

Now I want to apply this filter on a Location, that gets rewritten through a mod_rewrite rule

`RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}    ^\/wfs\/stripped\/
RewriteRule     ^/wfs/stripped/(.*) /cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/www/vhosts/mapserver/maps/$1.map&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]`

But the filter never gets applied, I guess this is because of the sequence of rules applied. However I could not find a solution for that problem

Answer (score 0):

Apply the full path, only clientside sees the rewritten URLs by mod_rewrite